# Сеттеры в классах JS

Tags: javascript, классы, getter, setter

Добрые вечер, прохожу курс JS. Попался вот такой код:

```html
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    // вызывает сеттер
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value) {
    if (value.length < 4) {
      alert("Имя слишком короткое.");
      return;
    }
    this._name = value;
  }

}

let user = new User("Иван");
alert(user.name); // Иван

user = new User(""); // Имя слишком короткое.
```

Вопрос следующий: в this.name у нас в итоге после сеттера записывается "Иван"? Или у нас `this.name = name` используется только для вызова сеттера? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: UPD в телефоне не увидел, геттер вы все же используюте.в alert

Comment: @Greg-- смотрите, я правильно понимаю: 'this.name' у нас является просто сеттером и туда мы ничего не можем записать? Таким образом this.name = name через знак равно мы передаем переменную "Иван". Верно?

Comment: this.name - геттер, this.name = "new name" - сеттер

Comment: Сеттер записывает, геттер читает. Тут моя ошибка, с телефона ничего не увидел, вы в конструкторе вызываете сеттер. Потом вам чтоб получить значение (геттер) достаточно вызвать user.name, чтоб задать новое имя user.name = "new name".

Comment: Редко вижу чтоб в конструкторе сеттер вызывали